# Is this reasoning of Chinese Remainder Theorem correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Originally I want to prove $y^{p'} \equiv x^n + C \pmod p$ is always having integer solution for some prime $p$ and $p'$

It is given by my classmate, so I do not know if it can really be proved, but this question is about my approach as stated below:

If $y \equiv x^n + C \pmod 3 $ has integer solution for some integers $n$ and $C$,

then **is it correct to say**, by *Chinese Remainder Theorem*:

there exists some integer $z$ which $y \equiv z^n + C \pmod p$ for some prime $p$?

As $3$ and $p$ must be co-prime.

If yes, then I think the original statement is also proved (assuming I can prove $y \equiv x^n + C \pmod 3$)

If no, please tell me what is wrong behind my reasoning of this approach. Thanks.

Comment: Was there supposed to be a $3$ in the original? Otherwise, where did the $3$ come from?

Comment: no, the original statement is more complicated indeed, but if p = 3, I can easily proof it.  So my approach is making use of this, and argue that if the statement is true when p = 3, then it is true for all prime other than 3 by chinese remainder theorem, and the application of CRT here is the part I am not sure about

Comment: CRT only says something about the existence of simultaneous solutions to equations which already trivially have solutions individually. So there is not really any way to apply CRT here.

Comment: For the original question, it is not quite clear to me which variables are being solved for, but one simplification is that $y^p \equiv y \pmod p$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay..I will try another approach then...I have a thought like this because I saw "Suppose n1, ..., nk are positive integers that are pairwise coprime. Then, for any given sequence of integers a1, ..., ak, there exists an integer x solving the following system of simultaneous congruences." on wiki... Thanks

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Omg, my bad sorry! I have edited the question. The power of y may not be the same as the modular p, but they are both prime numbers...Sorry!